# How to send an alert in aframe

Tags: javascript, alert, aframe

*I am using the aframe webvr library and testing on a Samsung Gear VR (galaxy s7 if that is relevant).*

I am trying to use JavaScript "alert" to present a message to the user before redirecting them to a different page.

However when this is run on the Gear VR in full screen mode, the alert message is not displayed, and full screen mode is simply exited, and the user is sent to another page without reading the content of the alert. How can I correctly display this message to VR users? (PS. The alert message works correctly on desktop and when the VR user is not in full screen mode)

Comment: I'd recommend to abandon `alert` and migrate to an HTML-based dialog.

Answer (score 0):

On a Samsung gear HMD ( or any other to be honest ) the `alert()` should be useless, since it belongs to the DOM's window element, and not the a-frame canvas.

That being said, there is no way Your user would be able to 'click' on the alert notification, unless you want Your website to turn back to 2D and act like a normal website with gear's default cursor.

I would recommend creating another a-frame element, which needs to be clicked in order to confirm the redirect.